# Select all from table where another query retuns no results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a register web application for someone and I want to make student search to add a student to the activities register slightly more accurate.

At the moment my prepared statement is:

```
("SELECT * FROM students WHERE first_name LIKE :pattern OR last_name LIKE :pattern OR id LIKE :pattern ORDER BY last_name ASC");
```

And that works great. I returns a list of all students that match the search query. However after doing that query, for each row that returns I want to check if the students.id and $_GET['activity'] do not appear in the participants table already.

$_GET['activity'] is an ID from activities.id

**The final result I want is to display all students that are not already registered on that activity.**

Is this possible in one query? As if it is I'd rather do that then have to run a query on each returns result to see whether it should be displayed or not.

I have looked into INNER JOIN as I've used it before, but I don't feel that is what I need. My main issue is how to run that query to check if each result is in the participants table already.

Hopefully that will make sense as I'm finding it hard to work out how to word it in my head.

**My table structure:**

*students* - id PRIMARY KEY AI, first_name (varchar255), last_name (varchar255), dob (date)

*activities* - id PRIMARY KEY AI, title (varchar255), description (varchar255)

*participants* - id PRIMARY KEY AI, student_id (INT), activity_id (INT)

Comment: This can be done in one query, but what do you want to return from that query? Do you want the students that are not registered for that activity, or the students that are registered?

Comment: I'll add that to my question. Sorry for being unclear. I want to return the students that are not already registered in that activity.

Comment: The query you've shown selects a set of students. You haven't given us the slightest hint about how your database records student activities, though.

Comment: can you provide a look at your participants table structure?

Comment: Updated original post to include table structure. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a NOT IN clause combined with a subquery, something like this:

SELECT *  FROM students WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM student_activities)

Comment: What is `$_GET['activity']`? Is it `activities.id` or `activities.title`?

Comment: $_GET['activity'] is an activities.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT* Updating this to use the three tables in the question

If you want all students who do NOT have a certain activity, you use a query pattern like this. The `LEFT JOIN` retains all the records from the `students` table, and places `NULL` values in the columns from `activities` where the `ON` condition *fails to match.* You then throw in a `WHERE` condition to keep only those `NULL` values. Like so:

```
 SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
   FROM students s
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON s.id = p.student_id
   LEFT JOIN activities a ON p.activity_id = a.activity_id AND a.activity LIKE :act
  WHERE a.activity_id IS NULL
    AND ( s.first_name LIKE :a OR s.last_name LIKE :b OR etc etc )
```

If your input is an `activity_id`, it's even easier.

```
 SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
   FROM students s
   LEFT JOIN participants p ON s.id = p.student_id AND p.activity_id = :act
  WHERE p.activity_id IS NULL
    AND ( s.first_name LIKE :a OR s.last_name LIKE :b OR etc etc )
```

As you've noticed, `INNER JOIN` can't do this, because it leaves out the rows from the first table that don't match the ON condition. But those rows are the very ones you want, hence the `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL`.

Beware some things:

- Don't use LIKE to match `id` values.
- Don't use `SELECT *`. Instead, name the columns you want in your result set.
- The sequence of `OR ... LIKE` clauses in your filter for the student table is not going to perform very well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. The second query worked perfectly. I'm going to go away and read about LEFT JOIN so I can properly understand it before I go on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
"SELECT * FROM students WHERE first_name LIKE :pattern OR last_name LIKE :pattern OR id LIKE :pattern AND id NOT IN (select student_id From participants WHERE activity_id = activity)
```

Here 'activity' is **$_GET['activity']** .

Comment: Hi Milan, thanks for your suggestion. If I'm correct, NOT IN (select student_id FROM participants) will not work as there may be multiple entries of the same student_id in participants if they are a part of other activities. Eg if your searching on activities.id 2, but the student is already part of activities.id 1.

Comment: also, you have 2 `WHERE`s in your query, which is invalid sql syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to get the `studentid`s that are registered for `$_GET['activity']`, and then remove them from the returned rows using `NOT IN` in your `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT * FROM students 
WHERE 
   (first_name LIKE :pattern OR last_name LIKE :pattern OR id LIKE :pattern)
AND 
   id NOT IN 
        (SELECT student_id FROM participants WHERE activity_id = :activity)
ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

where `:activity` is the placeholder for `$_GET['activity']`